# how to solve "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have redux store like this

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { reducers } from './reducers';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**form.js**

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64';
import useStyles from './styles';
import { createPost } from '../../api';

const Form = () => {
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({ creator: '', title: '', message: '', tags: '', selectedFile: '' });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createPost(postData))

  };

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Typography variant="h6">create a memory</Typography>
        <TextField name="creator" variant="outlined" label="Creator" fullWidth value={postData.creator} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })} />
        <TextField name="title" variant="outlined" label="Title" fullWidth value={postData.title} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })} />
        <TextField name="message" variant="outlined" label="Message" fullWidth multiline rows={4} value={postData.message} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })} />
        <TextField name="tags" variant="outlined" label="Tags (coma separated)" fullWidth value={postData.tags} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value.split(',') })} />
        <div className={classes.fileInput}><FileBase type="file" multiple={false} onDone={({ base64 }) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })} /></div>
        <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Submit</Button>
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small"  fullWidth>Clear</Button>
      </form>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

**/actions/posts.js**

```
import * as api from '../api/index.js';

export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();

    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_ALL", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createPost(post);

    dispatch({ type: "CREATE", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

after submitting the form I am getting the error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions"

so what I am doing wrong here

my code Github repo: https://github.com/priyanshu740/memories-MERN

YT video from where I am learning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA&t=3397s

error message

[image]

Comment: Why did you import `createPost` from `api` file rather than the action creators file?

Comment: because at that time of tutorial from i am learning it didn't created the action creator folder separately @slideshowp2